# When importing an SVG into powerpoint or inkscape transparent sections turn black

Tags: macos, svg, powerpoint, inkscape

When I add an SVG file to powerpoint or inkscape the transparent sections turn black. However, opening in Gapplin or a browser such as Chrome shows no issue.

OS: 10.14.2 (18C54)
Powerpoint version: 16.21 (190115)

SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="1440"
height="606" viewBox="392.375339276098 169.601943186359
1658.8799999999999 698.1120000000001" preserveAspectRatio="none"><defs
id="bmaDefs"><marker id="Activator" refX="4" refY="0" markerWidth="8"
markerHeight="4" orient="auto" viewBox="0 -2 4 4"><polyline
points="0,2 4,0 0,-2" fill="none" stroke="#808080"
stroke-width="1px"/></marker><marker id="Inhibitor" refX="0" refY="0"
markerWidth="2" markerHeight="6" orient="auto" viewBox="0 -3 2
6"><line x1="0" y1="3" x2="0" y2="-3" fill="none" stroke="#808080"
stroke-width="2px"/></marker></defs><g transform="translate(875,
420)"><rect x="-122.5" y="-137.2" width="245" height="274.4"
stroke="none" fill="transparent"/><path d="M249,577 C386.518903,577
498,447.83415 498,288.5 C498,129.16585 386.518903,0 249,0
C111.481097,0 0,129.16585 0,288.5 C0,447.83415 111.481097,577 249,577
Z M262,563 C387.368638,563 489,440.102164 489,288.5 C489,136.897836
387.368638,14 262,14 C136.631362,14 35,136.897836 35,288.5
C35,440.102164 136.631362,563 262,563 Z" stroke="transparent"
fill="#FAAF40" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="scale(0.45)
translate(-250, -290)" onmouseover="BMA.SVGHelper.AddClass(this,
'modeldesigner-element-hover')"
onmouseout="BMA.SVGHelper.RemoveClass(this,
'modeldesigner-element-hover')" class="null"/><ellipse cx="5" cy="0"
rx="102" ry="124" stroke="none" fill="transparent"/><text x="0" y="0"
transform="translate(-115, -99)" font-size="31" font-family="OpenSans"
src="local('Segoe UI'), local('Frutiger'), local('Frutiger Linotype'),
local('Dejavu Sans'), local('Helvetica Neue'), local('HelveticaNeue'),
local('Arial'), local('sans serif'), local('sans-serif')"
fill="black">C0</text></g><g transform="translate(853.4517837205423,
399.1192765196926)"><path
d="M27.3,43.4l-2.2-0.8c-12-4.4-19.3-11.5-20-19.7c0-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.1-1.4c-5.4-2.6-9-7.3-10.5-12.3c-0.6-2-0.9-4.1-0.8-6.3c-4.7-1.7-8.2-4.7-10.3-8.2c-2.1-3.4-3.2-8.1-2.1-13.4c-6.7-1.8-12.5-4.3-15.9-5.8l-7.4,19.9l26.7,7.9L-17,9.1l-32.8-9.7l11.9-32l3,1.5c3.9,1.9,10.8,4.9,18.1,6.9c1.9-4,5.1-8.1,10-12.1c10.8-8.9,19.7-8.1,23.8-3.4c3.5,4,3.6,11.6-4.2,18.7c-6.3,5.7-16.2,5.7-25.7,3.8c-0.6,3.2-0.2,6.2,1.4,8.9c1.3,2.2,3.4,4,6.3,5.3C-3.4-8.3,0.7-13.2,8-16c15.9-6.1,19.9,0.2,20.7,2.2c2.1,5.2-2.4,11.8-10.1,15C11.5,4.2,5.1,5-0.3,4.4C-0.2,5.5,0,6.5,0.3,7.5c0.9,3.2,3,6.1,6.2,8C8,12.1,11,9,15,6.7C25,1,32.2,1.6,35.7,4.2c2.3,1.7,3.3,4.3,2.7,7.1c-1.1,5.3-7.6,9.7-17.5,11.8c-3.6,0.8-6.8,0.8-9.7,0.4c1,4.9,6,9.5,13.9,12.8l7.4-10.7l17.4,10.1l-3,5.1l-12.6-7.4L27.3,43.4L27.3,43.4z
M12.1,17.5c2.2,0.3,4.8,0.3,7.6-0.3c9.4-2,12.6-5.6,12.9-7.2c0.1-0.4,0-0.7-0.4-1c-1.4-1-6.2-1.7-14.1,2.9C15.2,13.4,13.2,15.4,12.1,17.5L12.1,17.5z
M0.6-1.5C5-1,10.3-1.7,16.3-4.2c5.4-2.3,7.4-6,6.9-7.3c-0.4-1-4.3-2.2-13,1.1C5-8.5,2-5.1,0.6-1.5L0.6-1.5z
M-10.8-22.8c7.8,1.4,15.2,1.3,19.5-2.6c4.7-4.2,5.4-8.4,3.7-10.4c-2.1-2.5-8.3-1.9-15.5,4.1C-6.5-28.9-9.1-25.9-10.8-22.8L-10.8-22.8z"
stroke="transparent" fill="#EF4137" stroke-width="8"
transform="scale(0.25)" onmouseover="BMA.SVGHelper.AddClass(this,
'modeldesigner-element-hover')"
onmouseout="BMA.SVGHelper.RemoveClass(this,
'modeldesigner-element-hover')" class="null"/></g></svg>
```

[image: As viewed in Gapplin]

[image: As viewed in Powerpoint or Inkscape]

Comment: Try changing `fill="transparent"` to `fill="none"` on the offending shape.